# Valgrind: cannot execute binary file (Ubuntu 1804 on Win10) using WSL

Tags: c++, ubuntu, valgrind, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have complied a cpp project with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors .\nodeLL.cpp .\os_LL.cpp .\testUnit.cpp -o testUnit.exe
```

However when I try to run valgrind on it I receive the following error:

```
valgrind: ./testUnit.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

I have installed valgrind using the documentation on their website.

[image]

I am guessing it has something to do with WSL maybe? (I know the -g is missing but I tried to add it and it didn't help)

Thank you!

Comment: Were there any compiler warnings/errors? Does the binary need any command line arguments? I can't see why it would not work on WSL.

Comment: Did you compile it as a Windows executable format and are trying to run it through valgrind in WSL? That version of valgrind might only understand linux format executables.

Comment: @Shawn I don't think GCC is available on Windows, so based on that command line, I assume he gave his Linux binary a .exe extension.

Comment: @Mansoor gcc is certainly available for Windows.

Comment: @Roman Timm Can you run the binary from the command line?

Comment: I have added an image of the compiling (which works) and the command for valgrind. Also, the executable runs in the command line. @Mansoor

Comment: @Shawn, GCC returns only .exe extension after I compile from VS Code.

Comment: @Shawn is probably right, based on your last image, I get the impression that you have compiled a Windows binary and are trying to run it on Linux, which will not work (Linux file paths do not have colons). If you want to use Valgrind, you need to compile the code on Linux through WSL. If you need help we this, [consult the documentation for Windows cross-platform builds using WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-cross-platform-development-with-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3-vcpkg-cmake-configuration-remote-headers-and-wsl/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem because I was running `gcc` compiler on Windows `cmd` and running `valgrind` by that binary file, it wouldn't work because `gcc` compiles that file to be run on Windows and we need to compile it from the same WSL to run valgrind on the same. I use this Makefile to compile and run C programs (you may refer to the folder structure in the screenshot):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -Iinclude

SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj
BIN_DIR = bin

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRCS))
BIN = $(BIN_DIR)\main

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

run:
    $(BIN).exe

clean:
    del /Q $(OBJ_DIR)\*
    del /Q $(BIN_DIR)\*
```

Run the same make on windows WSL (after cleaning the objs windows cmd created). Ensure you have `gcc` installed in wsl.
[image: running Valgrind on windows WSL VScode terminal after make]